# How to create positive edge detector behavioural code?

Tags: verilog

I'm currently trying to code a positive edge detector that changes its output every time a positive edge is detected.  I succeeded in building one with gate-level modelling, but now I need to build it using behavioral modelling. I tried building it using this foundation:

```
module pos_edge_det ( input sig,           
                      input clk,            
                      output pe);          
 
    reg   sig_dly;                         
 
    
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    sig_dly <= sig;
  end
 
  assign pe = sig & ~sig_dly;            
endmodule
```

I tried making code where in every positive edge it detects on the input, the output will always invert:

```
module posedgedet(in, out, clk, res);
input wire in,clk,res;
output wire out;

always @ (posedge in, posedge clk)
begin
out <= ~out;
end

endmodule
```

When compiling, it returned this following error

> Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/pos edge detect.v(8): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "out".

What does this error mean, and how do you properly use the `always` code to detect a positive edge on both input and clock pulse?

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you can not declare `out` as a `wire` when you assign to it inside an `always` block.  You need to declare `out` as a `reg`.  I posted your module on **edaplayground** and compiled it on several simulators, one of which produced this slightly more specific error message:

> out is declared here as wire.

At least that gives you a hint that there is something wrong with using `wire`.

There is also a problem with this line:

```
always @ (posedge in, posedge clk)
```

That will not be synthesized into a flip-flop.

I think you are looking for a module which will detect a posedge on `sig` and generate an output `pe` which will be a single-clock wide pulse and also generate an output `out` which will toggle every time a posedge on `sig` is seen.  I'm assuming your `res` signal is a reset.  I also included a simple testbench.

```
module pos_edge_det (
    input sig,           
    input clk,            
    input res,            
    output pe,
    output reg out
);          

    reg sig_dly;                         

    always @ (posedge clk or posedge res) begin
        if (res) begin
            sig_dly <= 0;
        end else begin
            sig_dly <= sig;
        end
    end

    assign pe = sig & ~sig_dly;            

    always @ (posedge clk or posedge res) begin
        if (res) begin
            out <= 0;
        end else if (pe) begin
            out <= ~out;
        end
    end
endmodule 


module tb;

reg clk, res, sig;
wire pe, out;

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk =~clk;
end

pos_edge_det dut (
        // Inputs:
    .clk  (clk),
    .res  (res),
    .sig  (sig),
        // Outputs:
    .out  (out),
    .pe   (pe)
);

initial begin
    sig = 0;
    res = 1;
    #20 res = 0;
    repeat (10) #30 sig = ~sig;
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```