# Clarification on uses of posedge in "if"

Tags: verilog

I'm trying my hand at teaching myself some Verilog. I'm trying to make a mod-10 counter that iterates every second or so. The code I'm trying to modify is some I found on an old forum.

I've tried to use a secondary counter that iterates on every rising edge of the 26th bit of "counter". Am I not allowed to check for such an event? How might I do this in other ways?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (!enable) begin 
        counter <= counter + 1;
        
        if (posedge counter[26]) begin 
            seven_output = seven_output + 1;  //iterate the cumulative output state every second ish
        end     
    end
end
```

Here, `seven_output` is just another counter whose purpose will be to iterate as described and will be passed to a separate module whose job it will be to determine what combined state of LEDs to return.

The only error description I'm being given is

> Line 73: Syntax error near "posedge".

Line 73 is the inner-most `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the syntax error because the usage of the `posedge` keyword is illegal in the following line:

```
    if (posedge counter[26]) begin
```

It is illegal because there is no timing event control.  For example, `@(posedge something)` uses the `posedge` keyword along with an edge control construct: `@( )`.

Instead of using `posedge` there, you should create separate logic for an [edge detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930471/how-to-create-positive-edge-detector-behavioural-code) of the `count[26]` signal; let's call it `pe_count26`.

Furthermore, I recommend separating your 2 counters into 2 separate `always` blocks.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (!enable) begin 
        counter <= counter + 1;    
    end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (pe_count26) begin 
        seven_output <= seven_output + 1;
    end
end
```

It is a recommended good coding practice to use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for sequential logic.  I changed your `seven_output` assignment accordingly.